# Odd behavior with Runnable and ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

I'm getting some really weird behavior with multithreading. I have two classes: DipoleTester and Dipole.

DipoleTester attempts to create several Dipole objects, and then run them asynchronously. The problem is that DipoleTester just runs all of its Dipole objects at once, rather than 2 at a time.

Here is DipoleTester:

```
public class DipoleTester {
    public static String DIR = "./save/";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Dipole trial;
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);      

        for (int r = 10; r < 13; r += 1) {
            double radius = (double) r / 10000.0;
            for (int matType = 0; matType < 3; matType++) {
                String name = "Simple_mat"+matType + "_rad" + radius;
                trial = new DipoleSimple(DIR + "Simple/", name);
                trial.materialType = matType;
                trial.RADIUS = radius;
                service.submit(trial);

            }
        }
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }
}
```

And here are the (relevant bits) from Dipole

```
public abstract class Dipole implements Runnable{
    ...     
    public void run() {
        initiate();
    }
    public void initiate() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date) + ": Starting: " + NAME);
        model = ModelUtil.create(NAME);
        model.modelNode().create("mod1");
        makeParams();
        makeVariables();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem now is that all the threads execute at once, even with the thread.sleep(5000)! I have no idea what's going on. Here is the console output:

```
05/08/2013 19:17:31: Starting: Simple_mat0_rad0.001
05/08/2013 19:17:31: Starting: Simple_mat1_rad0.001
05/08/2013 19:17:31: Starting: Simple_mat2_rad0.001
05/08/2013 19:17:31: Starting: Simple_mat0_rad0.0011
05/08/2013 19:17:31: Starting: Simple_mat1_rad0.0011
05/08/2013 19:17:31: Starting: Simple_mat2_rad0.0011
05/08/2013 19:17:31: Starting: Simple_mat0_rad0.0012
05/08/2013 19:17:31: Starting: Simple_mat1_rad0.0012
05/08/2013 19:17:31: Starting: Simple_mat2_rad0.0012
```

Comment: So you were thinking that since the thread pool only has 2 workers, those two would immediately lockup on the sleeps and the other tasks would have to wait? What are you trying to do here?? Why not use the scheduling service if you want them spread out in time?

Comment: Are you sure it's even getting to the `sleep`?  I trimmed your code down a bit to get it to compile and it worked as you expected, running 2 tasks and then sleeping 5 seconds before running another two tasks.  But I had to pull some code out to get it to work.  Maybe it's hitting an exception and never getting to the sleep?

Comment: Dear @randomafk, `sleep(5000)` should be placed in `DipoleTester` class after each loop.. you will not get benefited from the sleep while it's in the Runnable class, If you want to start a `sleep` after each thread then place `sleep(5000)` after ``service.submit(trial)``.Another thing is that why don't you use `service.execute(trial)` instead of `service.submit(trial)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Runnable` task is throwing an exception before it gets to the `Thread.sleep()` call. This allows the next task to begin execution. All the tasks fail in such quick succession that all appear to run concurrently.

Make the call to `Thread.sleep()` the first thing you do in your `run()` method and you will see that only two threads run at a time.

To detect such failures, you'll need to [examine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) the [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) instance that results from each call to `submit()`. There are [other methods for submitting a list of tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) in bulk, and waiting for them to complete, that might be better suited to your application.

Comment: Agree with this. I tried creating a simpler version of OP's code just to test and it works as he intended: http://pastebin.com/UQVuQ5ZL

Comment: Agreed as well per my previous comment :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried using callable and invokeAll() instead and it turns out the library I'm using is throwing exceptions all over the place... Any idea why it would working as a singlethread but not when I try to run them concurrently?

Comment: @randomafk I am not sure why it wouldn't work concurrently. I'd need more information, like, what does "not working" mean? Throws exceptions? Stack traces would help. What library is it that you are using? Etc. If you open a new question, feel free to comment here again with a link; I'd like to take a look.